# Forming a tuple/list from a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have file of format:

```
C1  A1
C2  A2
C3  A3  
C1  A4
C4  A5
```

Each line is separted by a tab. Can I get this file in array/list/tuple directly so that the columns of each line can be accessible through index?
Like [(c1,a1),(c2,a2)..]
Any python functions allows us to do this?

Comment: `[line.split() for line in open('/path/to/file')]`

Comment: @falsetru. Will that close the file automatically?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, It will in CPython. But using `with` statement is recommended.

Comment: @falsetru. Thanks, I didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do :

```
with open('filename.txt') as file:
  result = [line.split() for line in file]
```

It outputs :

```
>>> with open('filename.txt') as file:
...   result = [line.split() for line in file]
... 
>>> result
[['C1', 'A1'], ['C2', 'A2'], ['C3', 'A3'], ['C1', 'A4'], ['C4', 'A5']]
```